# Imitating standard user input in c++ with command line arguments

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

Let's say I have the following C++ Code

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
   int x,y;
   std::cout << "Please enter the first input." << std::endl;
   std::cin>>x;
   std::cout << "Please enter the second input." << std::endl;
   std::cin>>y;
   std::cout<<x/y<<std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

I can compile the file from command line with   `cl/EHsc sample.cpp`

what i want to do is to display the output(s) of the program with inputs given from the command line.How can i do this?

x should get it's value from the first command line argument,

y should get it's value from the second command line argument.

Following should work but i want to avoid fiddling with Visual Studio Properties etc.

[Piping input into a c++ program to debug in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613059/piping-input-into-a-c-program-to-debug-in-visual-studio)

Edit: Also for further clarification i want to use it as an automated system where it receives the input from the command line  and I do not want to modify the original code

Comment: argv[1] and argv[2] does not work?

Comment: I should've added that i do not want to modify the code itself,i edited the question, that is a valid point.

Comment: Write a shell script wrapper?

Comment: can you elaborate or give an example, how will the shell script wrapper pass the command line parameters to executable(as standard input) ?

Comment: `echo "arg1 arg2" | ./yourprogrnamehere` (oh wait, VS/Windows; nm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted answer of the "piping input" question you linked to applies to your question as well.  You don't have to fiddle with Visual Studio properties if you use a command line window to do it.  Just open up a command prompt and type it:

```
cd c:\path\to\project\debug
sample.exe < my_input.txt
```

Edit: WhozCraig's suggestion works too:

```
cd c:\path\to\project\debug
echo 6 2 | sample.exe
```