# How to setup environment like competitive programming sites in visual studio community?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-community

I'm trying to create environment like online competitive sites (Hackerearth.com, hackerrank.com and ideone.com) in visual studio community 2017 for coding practice.

Check this https://ideone.com/fuSOVO

Below is the standard structure for most of the questions in c++ code in competitive programming.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    string s;
    while (t--) {
        cin >> s;
        cout << " Hello " << s << "\n";
        cin.get();
    }   
}

input:
5
Sam
Kiara
Victor
Riley
Diva

output:
Hello Sam
Hello Kiara
Hello Victor
Hello Riley
Hello Diva
```

Almost all the competitive programming site are using stdin as the default input and stdout as default output like above.

I have used this guide https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-compile-and-run-C%2B%2B-in-Sublime-Text/answer/Shubham-Agrawal-131?srid=n9sL to setup the environemt in Sublime Text. And it is working perfectly fine. Now I want to set up the same in Visual Studio Community 2017.

I followed this guide [Piping input into a c++ program to debug in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613059/piping-input-into-a-c-program-to-debug-in-visual-studio) but i'm getting error.

```
'FirstProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'F:\Visual Studio\FirstProject\Debug\FirstProject.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'FirstProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FirstProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FirstProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FirstProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FirstProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'FirstProject.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The program '[3764] FirstProject.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I know I can use file system but when I have to upload the code from my local system to online editor, I have to change the code to match to those site's environment. I want to create the same environment on my local so that I don't have to change the code every time while submitting on the site.

Comment: These aren't errors. Just telling you that there's no `PDB` files and source code could be loaded for your debugging session.

Comment: I'm very new to visual studio. I'm not getting any output but those.

Comment: So what's your problem then?

Comment: just read files and output into files within your program, why are you making this so complex?

Comment: like this `freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);` right ? I can use this in Visual studio but the online editor doesn't allow to use that. (Maybe I'm wrong and I don't know how to use that). As I mentioned that I have to change this code every time while submitting the code on online editor. I hope you get what I actually want. It will very helpful if you give an example.

Answer (score 0):

Add

> input.txt

to the project and
Try this

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
try
{
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4996) //4996 for _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS equivalent
    freopen("intput.txt", "r", stdin);
#pragma warning(pop)
#endif

    int n; // number of workshops
    cin >> n;

}
catch (...) {
    cout << "Error" << endl;
}
#ifdef _MSC_VER
fclose(stdin);
#endif
return 0;
}
```

the #ifdef will cause the code to not be used by the compiler outside of VS