# Print a sequence of strings with one missplaced string

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm doing an exercise for fun (not homework), where given a sequence of strings sorted, with one word that appears too soon, we have to print the sequence sorted.
The point is that we have to do it with O(1) auxiliary space, so no `vector` nor `list`

I tried the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string current, next, mal;
    bool trobat = false;
    cin >> current >> next;
    while (next != "END") {

        if (trobat) {
            if (mal > current and mal < next) {
                cout << current << endl;
                cout << mal << endl;
                trobat = false;
            }
            else {
                cout << current << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (current < next) {
            cout << current << endl;
        }
        else {
            trobat = true;
            mal = current;
            cout << next << endl;
        }
        current = next;
        cin >> next;
    }
    if (trobat) {
        cout << mal << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << current << endl;
    }
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to have 3 strings: one with the current value to be treated, one with the next and one with the bad placed word, called `mal`.
`trobat` indicates if the word not sorted has been found but not printed yet.

If the word is correctly placed, we print it with the `else if (current < next)`.
If not, I activate the flag trobat and print the next value, because the next has to be sorted.
Then, for the first if, if I found the value, I check if `mal` is in the right position, otherwise I print the current and repeat the process.

I'm having troubles with the following tests:

INP1:

```
a
b
e
c
d
f
g
END
```

OUT1:

```
a
b
c
c
d
e
f
g
```

expected OUT1:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

INP2:

```
f
aaaaaa
bbbbb
cccc
ddd
ee
END
```

OUT2:

```
aaaaaa
aaaaaa
bbbbb
cccc
ddd
f
```

expected OUT2:

```
aaaaaa
bbbbb
cccc
ddd
ee
f
```

Comment: Note that you are appending all your input strings into `s`. This is definitely not `O(1)` space, and at that point you might as well use a vector. Also, you need to show the output of your program.

Comment: @cigien wrote in the OP that I'm using s for debugging purposes only. I'm going to edit with the output.

Comment: Oh, that's true. Yes, edit in the output you get.

Comment: @cigien I added the value of `s`, because the terminal is showing the inputs and outputs at the same time and everything is a mess... Hope it makes sense.

Comment: *"the terminal is showing the inputs and outputs at the same time"*. You might create file with all input, and then do `cat input.txt | my_app.exe`. that would not mix input/output. (but no longer be interactive).

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm on a windows machine, using Visual Studio

Comment: Then see [piping-input-into-a-c-program-to-debug-in-visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613059/piping-input-into-a-c-program-to-debug-in-visual-studio)

Comment: @Jarod42 Interesting, so you can use  `>` operator in VS. I'm going ot edit the question. Feel free to give it a try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify the code to:

```
std::string word1;
std::string word2;
 
std::cin >> word1 >> word2;
 
while (word2 != "END") {
    std::cout << std::min(word1, word2) << std::endl;
    word1 = std::max(word1, word2);
    std::cin >> word2;
}
std::cout << word1 << std::endl;
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/PPKPrr)

Comment: Beautifuly done! I didn't think about this one... Much more elegant than a bunch of if's